# backbone marionette composite view not firing events

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Here is the code compositeView snippet using which i'm creating tree structure.

```
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: "#filterTemplate",
    className:"menuItem",
    tagName: "ul",

    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = this.model.type;
        counter=0;
    },

    events: {
        'click .menuItem': 'show'
    },

    show: function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        console.log(target);

    },

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
        // ensure we nest the child list inside of 
        // the current list item
        $(itemView.el).attr("id","innerMenu"+counter);
        $(itemView.el).attr("class","innerMenu");
        collectionView.$("li:first").append(itemView.el);
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Tree is rendered perfect but events are not getting bind or not fired. Show method is never called.  i'm using Backbone.Marionette v0.9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the view itself set up to render with the `menuItem` css class. In any backbone view (this is not specific to Marionette), if you want to handle an event on the view's element directly (not one of it's children), you specify your event without a selector.

In your case, it would be:

```
events: {
    "click": "show"
}
```

This will configure the view's `el` with the "click" event directly, and the `show` method will be called when you click any part of this view's HTML.

Comment: Thank you derick..it was helpful :) I was wondering if i can add events only to main menu not sub menu items.